# How do I put borders on specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, border

I have an Excel file that is sorted by article, id and launch date, which means I have several rows with the same article.

I want to put bottom borders under all the rows that have the same article.

I have this but it only puts borders under the header row.

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For Each x In Range("G1").End(xlDown)
    count = count + 1
    Range(Cells(count, 1), Cells(count, 16)).Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlBottom)
     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
     .Color = vbBlack
     .Weight = xlThick
    End With
Next x
```

Comment: Does column A have the articles?

Comment: No, it's in column G, and I the file has variant number of rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to highlight the very bottom of your data, offset the upper bound of the loop by 1 with `ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`

```
Sub BorderPatrol()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("G" & i) <> ws.Range("G" & i - 1) Then
        With ws.Range("G" & i - 1).EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom) 
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```